# What could cause a 401 error in a git pull (via libgit2sharp)?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

This is my Pull wrapper which works on my local network:

```
internal MergeStatus Pull()
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(repositoryRoot))
    {
        var merger = new Signature(userName,emailAddress,DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);

        var options =new PullOptions {  
            FetchOptions = new FetchOptions()
                {
                    CredentialsProvider = CredentialsHandler
                }
            };

        MergeResult result = repo.Network.Pull(merger, options);
        return result.Status;
    }
}
```

The following shows the CredentialsHandler I am using along with the commented-out attempt to use UsernamePasswordCredentials which gave me exactly the same result.

```
public LibGit2Sharp.Handlers.CredentialsHandler CredentialsHandler 
{
    get
    {
        if (credentialsHandler_ == null)
        {
            credentialsHandler_ = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials();

            //This does not fix the 401 error on Jupiter box
            //credentialsHandler_ = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
            //{
            //  Username = userName,
            //  Password = pwd,
            //};
        }
        return credentialsHandler_;
    }

    set
    {
        credentialsHandler_ = value;
    }
}
```

The Pull function works beautifully on the local network but when I use it from a machine on a different network but with an identical directory structure and clone of the git repository, I get this 401 error:

> LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Request failed with status code:
>   401    at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result)    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_fetch(RemoteSafeHandle remote,
>   Signature signature, String logMessage)    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Network.DoFetch(RemoteSafeHandle remoteHandle,
>   FetchOptions options, Signature signature, String logMessage)    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Network.Fetch(Remote remote, FetchOptions options,
>   Signature signature, String logMessage)    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Network.Pull(Signature merger, PullOptions options)    at
>   GitFace.GitFileListController.Pull() in
>   c:\Code\Workspace\GitFace\GitFileListController.cs:line 190

Note that when I use git bash and enter 'git pull', I need to enter a password on both the local and network computers but both successfully pull the changes from the remote repository (FWIW, the actual repository is in TFS on the local network). My process for pulling and pushing via git bash is identical for the two computers so I was surprised when the libgit2sharp code behaved differently from one to the other.

Note: This did NOT work:

```
private int GitCredentialHandler(out IntPtr ptr, IntPtr cUrl, IntPtr usernameFromUrl, GitCredentialType credTypes, IntPtr payload)
        {
            string url = LaxUtf8Marshaler.FromNative(cUrl);
            string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
            if (url.StartsWith(@"http://"))
            {
                url = string.Format(@"http://{0}\\\{1}", domain, url.Substring(7));
            }
            else if (url.StartsWith(@"https://"))
            {
                url = string.Format(@"https://{0}\\\{1}", domain, url.Substring(8));
            }

            string username = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, LaxUtf8Marshaler.FromNative(usernameFromUrl));
            SupportedCredentialTypes types = default(SupportedCredentialTypes);
            if (credTypes.HasFlag(GitCredentialType.UserPassPlaintext))
            {
                types |= SupportedCredentialTypes.UsernamePassword;
            }
            if (credTypes.HasFlag(GitCredentialType.Default))
            {
                types |= SupportedCredentialTypes.Default;
            }

            var cred = CredentialsProvider(url, username, types);

            return cred.GitCredentialHandler(out ptr);
        }
```

Comment: `DefaultCredentials` should work, but there may be a bug in NTLM handling for specified (eg `DOMAIN\username` and `password`) credentials.  I'll take a closer look!

Comment: I have tried hacking RemoteCallbacks::GitCredentialHandler but it didn't seem to have any effect - still got 401...

Comment: Got the same problem. No idea why. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to always inform the username and password (change to appsettings/secrets) and I was successful.

```
private void FazerPullDeUmRepositorio(Repository repo)
{
    string gitUser = "[my.user.name-here]", gitToken = "[my-password-or-token-here]";
            
    var options = new PullOptions
    {
        FetchOptions = new FetchOptions { CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = gitUser, Password = gitToken } }
    };

    var email = repo.Config.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "user.email").Value;
    var nome = repo.Config.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "user.name").Value;
    var usuario = new Signature(nome, email, DateTime.Now);

    Logs.AdicionarInfo($"\nPull iniciado em: '{ObterNomeDoRepositorio(repo)}'");
    MergeResult resultado;
            
    try
    {
        resultado = Commands.Pull(repo, usuario, options);
    }
    catch (LibGit2SharpException ex)
    {
        if (ex is CheckoutConflictException exConclito)
        {
            Logs.AdicionarErro($"Temos conflito(s) no repositório {ObterNomeDoRepositorio(repo)}.");
            return;
        }
        else if (ex.Message.Equals("There is no tracking information for the current branch."))
        {
            Logs.AdicionarSucesso("Branche só existe local.");
            return;
        }

        throw;
    }
```